# Admin filter/error if post title is too long

Tags: filters, admin, title

Is there a filter that will throw an error if the posts creator enters a post title that is too long?

I am looking to throw an error like: "The title you've entered is more than 30 characters. Please change the title and try again." Preferably this might be a banner alert like standard errors or at least something noticeable. In addition the post will not be saved until the title is of the correct length.

I know there is the wp_insert_post_data filter where you can modify the title before it is saved, but I don't want to do something like truncating as it might not make sense to the end user. This is something I would like the post writer to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the transition_post_status.

```
function check_post_title_length($new_status, $old_status, $post){

    if($new_status == 'auto-draft' || $new_status == 'draft'){
        return;
    }

    if(str_word_count($post->post_title, 0) > 12){
        //update-nag is the term for a yellow warning box in admin_notices
        //notice here I use the WP_Error data field to choose the type of error box to show
        $admin_notices = new WP_Error('check_post_title_length','If possible, consider making the post title shorter.', 'update-nag');
        //we could also if we needed, add more notices to the list such as
        //$admin_notices->add('some_other_check', 'Sorry you need to add an author');
        add_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'admin_notices', $admin_notices, true);
    }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'check_post_title_length', 10, 3);

function display_admin_notices(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $admin_notices = get_user_meta($user_id, 'admin_notices', true);

    if(!empty($admin_notices)){
        //make sure its a WP_Error object
        if(is_wp_error($admin_notices)){
            //delete error from user meta so error is gone on page reload
            delete_user_meta($user_id, 'admin_notices');
            $notices = $spm_admin_notices->get_error_messages();

            if(!empty($notices)){
                $notice_type = $admin_notices->get_error_data();
                if(!empty($notice_type)){
                ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $notice_type; ?>">
                <?php
                } else {
                ?>
                    <div class="error">
                <?php
                }
                //here we loop through all notices we want to display
                //this is useful if the user needs to adjust more than one item
                foreach($notices AS $notice){
                ?>
                    <p><?php echo $notice; ?></p>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'display_admin_notices');
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing I think you're missing is understanding that WordPress doesn't use a linear path for saving posts. Because posts are autosaved you'll want to handle this in a way that defines it according to it's publish status rather than it's save state. Basically, instead of trying to truncate or adjust the title, do your check in the `wp_insert_post_data` or via a [post status transition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) and prevent the post from being set to a `publish` or `future` status until all of your conditions are met. The action for an admin notice is [`admin_notices`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices).

Comment: Whats the best way to implement the admin_notices here since it runs on every page load. I hate coupling business logic in the notices function thats actually based on another function; just feels wrong.